# How to add an object into an existing layout in qt? --Solved

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlayout

I am working on a qt project and I am trying to add an object as a widget into my layout, how can I do that?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        GLobj obj; //this is the object I want to add and it extends QGLWidget
        QWidget *window = new QWidget;
        QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;

        grid->addWidget(&obj,0,0,4,5);//it works

        window->setLayout(grid);            
        window->show();
        return app.exec();
 }
```

Comment: Maybe, you have to indicate row and column for [QGridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1)

Comment: @AntonShwarts I would strike out the *Maybe*. ;-)

Comment: no, it doesn't work, it says no matching function call.

Comment: Is GLobj a derived class from a QWidget?

Comment: Please update your question to show the latest code you've tried as well as any error messages verbatim.

Comment: It makes no sense to cast a value `GLobj` to a pointer `QWidget*`. Just pass `&obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QGridLayout::addWidget` method expects *a pointer* to an instance of a QWidget-derived class, thus if `GLobj` happens to be something like:

```
class GLobj : public QWidget
{
...
```

you can do:

```
grid->addWidget(&obj);
```

Comment: it extends QGLWidget class

Comment: @Ashley that still doesn't solve the fact that you passed/cast it wrongly.

Comment: yeah, you are right! After adjusting the display parameter, I finally made it show. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as in the doc specified [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addWidget),

```
addWidget(*Widget, row, column, rowspan, colspan)
```

so replace

```
grid->addWidget(obj);//I'm not able to do it..
```

with

```
grid->addWidget(obj, 1, 1, 2, 2); //Now I'm able to do it.. :)
```

Comment: or `grid->addWidget(obj, 1, 1);`